# Installed Ubuntu, the max. resolution is 800x600

Tags: ubuntu, resolution

I installed ubuntu, but the screen size is very small 800x600.

I can't change the setting, what could be the issue?

Comment: What card are you using? ATI/nVidia? as eleven81 said below, its most likely because the drivers for your graphics card are not installed. If you goto the nVidia site you can download the linux drivers as a .deb, try running that

Answer (score 6):

The correct drivers for your video card are probably not installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in ubuntu 9.10 in spite of having correct drivers.I was able to increase my resolution to 1028x following instructions given vide http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8302145#post8302145.You may also try.

Answer (score 0):

Try reconfiguring the X server. Open the terminal, type

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Logout & login or restart your system.